# EJB lookup externelization

Tags: annotations, ejb, jndi, lookup, using

I am calling remote EJB invocation in my another java/ejb class as below:

@EJB(lookup="ejb jndi path"
private MYEJBRemote myEjbRemote; //This EJB is in another EAR Application

Issue is:

I would like to eliminate the above JNDI path hardcoding in the code.

Please help.

Comment: Why you need JNDI for remote call?

Answer (score 0):

I see one not simple solution. You may realize additionally service on the server, on which deployed EJB. This service would have one function, which return JNDI name of the EJB for remote access by EJB name or specified interface (for example). Not simple moment: in this function you will need to search remote EJB through JNDI tree of server - realization would server specific.